# how to get UITableviewCell textlabel frame

Tags: ios, swift, frame, uitableview

i am trying to get the `UITableviewCell` `textlabel` frame as
 `frm = CGFloat(cell.textLabel?.frame.width)`  but getting an error. Can anyone say how to get the value in swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the frame and the width as follows:

```
let frame = cell.textLabel?.frame
var frameWidth = frame.size.width
```

Comment: yah..but why is it showing me value 320.0 as of size of tableviewcell?

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: No.i am not using autolayout